# How to store file in Windows OS instead of `/tmp` unix?

Tags: python, windows, file, urllib

The following code works good on unix-base system, and use `/tmp` for store file, But how can I use it under windows OS family?

```
    local_filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve('http://127.0.0.1/translations/python-3.7.3.exe')
    print(local_filename)
    fd = open(local_filename)
    fd.close()
```

Comment: You can provide a  `filename` argumemt

Comment: Did you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs:

> Retrieve a URL into a temporary location on disk.

If you don't supply the `filename` argument, then `urlretrieve()` will call `tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()` to create a file on whatever is the location for temporary files on your operating system. That works under Windows too (the file will be created under `%TEMP%`).

If you want a specific location, pass a `filename` argument.